# ng-include in ui-bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am testing angularJS and ui-bootstrap tooltips :

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

What I want to achieve is a tooltip with some working buttons inside.

I have tried :

```
<input type="text" value="{{activity.name}}"
tooltip-html-unsafe='<button class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" ng-click="addChild(activity)">+</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" ng-click="remove(activity)">X</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" ng-click="removeChildren(activity)" ng-show="activity.children.length > 0">X children</button>'
tooltip-trigger="focus"
tooltip-placement="right" />
```

Which is ugly and does not work. The buttons are rendered but do not execute the 'ng-click'.

Is there some way I can tell the tooltip to fetch a partial and keep the ng-click functional ?

Comment: Have you tried binding the template string to a variable and calling it that way? i.e. `$scope.tooltipHTML = "templateString"` `<input tooltip-html-unsafe='{{tooltipHTML}}' />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tooltips that would contain "live" HTML (with AngularJS directives working etc.) are not supported in the current (0.5.) version of http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

You might want to open a feature request for this in https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues?state=open

Comment: Thanks, I have opened a pull request : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/781